# Based on mobile number, how do i get country code in JavaScript or Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way to find the country code from my mobile number? Basically, I am working on a chat application I need to find the country code by using the mobile number. Is it possible?

Comment: You could easy find this with a quick search: https://countrycode.org/

Comment: I don't understand why you ask this question. If you're trying to find the country code for your phone number, why ask in stack overflow? Please elaborate on your question

Comment: can you please specify the exact problem you want to solve.

Comment: Please refactor your question bo be a little more specific. Are you just trying to find out a country code then @PEPEGA s comment was already more than enough and this question does not belong here. Or are you trying to show the Country a Mobile number belongs to on your website. Then you will need to integrate an API as a service with angular. An API could be this one https://restcountries.eu/#api-endpoints-full-name

Comment: my problem is i try to enter without any country code mobile number  in html input field then after submit. how can i get country code based on mobile, is their any script code or API.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ngx-international-phone-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-international-phone-number) package, so users can select the country and can input their phone number.

Comment: if you have any demo link plz share it.

Answer (score 0):

Store in a DB country code and make a query

Comment: how can i find this mobile number belongs to this coutry.

Comment: every country have an unique phone code like https://countrycode.org/  Format for a number is +(country code in generaly contain 3 number) and phone number

Comment: if i enter without country code.how can i get?

Comment: without country code you cant because country code is the way to find country otherwise it is just a number, if you receive a call and you dont see country code then the number caller have same country code as you